# how to overcome if an api throws 404,400 error response in http request node,node red

Tags: node-red, mattermost

When I call an API using http request node for invalid parameters my     api throws an 404,400 error and I am trying to show **Invalid Data** as a response.

When I trigger the api getting the response on browser that what we are expecting.

But, when I try on the client mattermost it's throwing an error saying

```
{"name":"StatusCodeError","statusCode":404,"message":"404"}
```

I think it is not going into the next node of my flow where I written the if statement.

Can any one help me how to overcome this issue.

> response :- { "_msgid": "22d03407.5d9fac", "payload": "{\"**all**\":
>   [\"xxxx with ID xxxx not found\"]}", "url": "xxxxxxxxx", "statusCode":
>   404, "headers": { "server": "nginx", "date": "Fri, 27 Jan 2017
>   12:25:11 GMT", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>   "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "connection": "close", "vary":
>   "Accept, Cookie", "set-cookie": [ "uid=rB8uFViLPCdOjlIIA0mqAg==;
>   path=/" ], "p3p": "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"" }, "req": { "_readableState": {
>   "objectMode": false, "highWaterMark": 16384, "buffer": { "head": null,
>   "tail": null, "length": 0 }, "length": 0, "pipes": null, "pipesCount":
>   0, "flowing": null, "ended": true, "endEmitted": false, "reading":
>   false, "sync": true, "needReadable": false, "emittedReadable": true,
>   "readableListening": false, "resumeScheduled": false,
>   "defaultEncoding": "utf8", "ranOut": false, "awaitDrain": 0, ....

Comment: Update the question with what you get out of the http-request node when you attach a debug node (set to whole message)

Comment: fixed the issue by hardcoding the statusCode in my flow....Its working fine from the client too.                                                                                                         Thanks!